# Can I continue using a pymongo cursor object after an AutoReconnect exception?

Tags: mongodb, cursor, pymongo

When you receive an AutoReconnect exception from a database query, a common practice is to wait a bit then try the query again (perhaps ad-infinitum in some contexts).

If this happens while traversing a cursor, does it make sense to continue attempting to get data from the same cursor object, or do I have to create a new one and start from scratch? Are pymongo cursor objects able to handle this situation gracefully without missing data?

Let's assume the problem was some sort of temporary network interruption, and that the server is fine (and hence should still know about the cursor).

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is stored on the MongoDB server, and all operations are also performed on the server (e.g. sorting, limiting, etc). Besides, the server transfers the data to the client in chunks (see [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) for more details).

So imagine the following scenario:

```
         Client                        Server
         ------                        ------
           |                              |
           |                              |
       make query  =======================>
           |                              |
           |                        process query
           |                              |
           |                       construct cursor
           |                              |                   +--------+
           |                         store cursor ----------> | Cursor |
           |                              |                   +--------+
           <===================== return cursor/chunk
           |                              |
   iterate half chunk                     |
           |                         SERVER GOES DOWN
           |             -----------------------------------------------------------
           |                              :                      X
  iterate till the end                    :                      ^
           |                        SERVER COMES LIVE            |
           |                              |                      |
 request the next chunk ==================> ---------------------+ The cursor no longer exists
           |                              |
           <============================= |
           |    server responds with a    |
           |    pretty much intelligent   |
           |            error             |
```

If you run this scenario on the Mongo Shell, you will get a nice `Error: getMore: cursor didn't exist on server, possible restart or timeout?`.

Thus, it would be reasonable to start the request from the beginning.